# Azure Active Directory Getting code 403 with Client Credentials Grant

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function that I have secured using Azure Active Directory  (using express settings)

I generated an secret key and was able to get the other bits required (client id, tenant etc).I followed this guide to test the Client Credentials
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds .

I was able to get an access token but when I try to access the function using the Bearer Token I get error code `403` with `'You do not have permission to view this directory or page.'`

How can I fix this? I want to secure my Azure function using a secret key.

Edit ----------

I want to access my Azure function http endpoint.

The requests I have used:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token/
```

With body:

```
client_id:{Application Id in Azure AD}
scope:https://{functionname}.azurewebsites.net/.default // This might be the source of the problem
client_secret:{Key Generated}
grant_type:client_credentials
```

This returns an access token eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJS.....

Then 
`Get`  http endpoint of my AzureFunction

```
https://{functionName}.azurewebsites.net/api/endpoint?Params
The Header contains Authorization Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJS.....
```

Comment: What was the value of `resource` when you requested the token?

Comment: First, as @juunas asked, please post more details about your issue. e.g ,What's the resource value of  Auth URL and Access token URL in your request? Second, if you want to use the access token to access one resource, you should get the token of that resources, NOT  from another resource.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT I updated the question.

Comment: How can I set the resource. the guide doesn't mention anything about that. @juunas

Comment: Oh wait this was v2 :) No resource needed. The scope probably is the problem..

Comment: that is my guess too but I wasn't able to find any documentation regarding scope usage for an Azure Function.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid of that Azure function doesn't support  v2 endpiont. First, if you want to use the v2 endpoint authentication flow, you also need to configure your function app to use the v2 endpoint application. As I known, we cannot configure it directly. So, you can use azure active directory the Express settings to authenticate the Function app in azure portal. Also, why not use the v1 endpoint to achieve your requirement?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT the Azure Active Directory didn't mention anything about using the version 1.0. Can you provide any links or guide me to the correct direction to how to achieve this. I want to secure an Azure Function using a secret key ( clients with secret keys must access the service without any prompts). Thanks

Comment: Here is a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code). NOTE: Since you configure the authentication with Azure AD with Express settings, it should exist one application in azure ad . You can find it and refer the above document to use it. It should work for you.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT Thanks for the document you sent but it details how to use auth grant which requires an inetraction with the user.
I was able to access the resource now using this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service 
And using the application id instead of the Application URI ( for some weird reason)